# Error Missage When Loading Photo: CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef

Tags: filter, gpuimage, cgimageref

I have an app I am creating, which uploads images to a server. I used GPUImage, and GKImagePicker libraries when cropping the image and adding filters. I am not adding any filters at this point, so I don't think the filters is the problem. I think the problem is in the GKImagePicker Library. I am getting this error:

CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef.

This was working before I upgraded to Xcode 7 recently.

I saw this other post on StackOverflow:
[Getting message in console: "CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632085/getting-message-in-console-createwrappedsurface-failed-for-a-dataprovider-ba)

I tried to make the change that was made in this post with the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds, NO, 1.0f); line, but this did not fix my issue. I think I might be missing something else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks